# disable Find bugs in maven

Tags: maven, findbugs

The team are using find bugs. I would like to skip using find bugs.

I can see it has an option maven.findbugs.enable,but I don't know how to use that as an  argument to maven.

I have tried - Dmaven.findbugs.enable=false but I can see find bugs is still running.

What is the argument to stop findbugs?

Comment: Did you try using `-Dfindbugs.skip=true`? https://gleclaire.github.io/findbugs-maven-plugin/check-mojo.html#skip

Comment: The only mention of the `maven.findbugs.enable` parameter date from the 1.4 version from 2007 ! http://maven-plugins.sourceforge.net/maven-findbugs-plugin/properties.html What version are you using?

Comment: @halfer hi. you've made 8 comments against me in 10 mins... did I upset you? I meant see in this case

Comment: @bharal: you have not upset me at all, no - comments are usually a good thing. (If I point out a typographical error, please fix it, so that the question is in a readable condition for future readers. I have fixed it on this occasion).

Comment: (Ah, I think the messages you have received are _edit notifications_ - I didn't think I had commented that number of times. Obviously, post improvements are good to receive too.)

Comment: Both -Dfindbugs.skip=true, -Dfindbugs.skip didn't work for me. I wanted to use it as a workaround for the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53676071/maven-clean-command-java-util-collections-unmodifiablerandomaccesslist-to-prope/55834783#55834783, but I got the error anyway:

Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.3:findbugs for parameter pluginArtifacts: Cannot assign configuration entry 'pluginArtifacts' with value '${plugin.artifacts}' of type java.util.Collections.UnmodifiableRandomAccessList to property of type java.util.ArrayList

Answer (score 29):

If you are using FindBugs 3.x:

```
mvn [goal] -Dfindbugs.skip=true
```

According to the [FindBugs documentation](https://gleclaire.github.io/findbugs-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html). This should work for the `check` and `findbugs` goals.

Comment: Or shortened version: mvn [goal] -Dfindbugs.skip

Answer (score 27):

Although unrelated to this question, `Spotbugs` is the successor of `Findbugs` and to skip it we need to pass the below flag:

```
-Dspotbugs.skip=true
```

Answer (score 5):

Run the following for `maven` version `3.0.5` and above.

```
mvn [goal] -Dfindbugs.skip
```

Answer (score -2):

Although the above answers work, I found that this error disappeared for me when I downgraded from `Java 11` to `Java 8`. For reference, I am using Maven version `3.3.9`.