# Maven clean command: java.util.Collections.UnmodifiableRandomAccessList to property of type java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, maven, findbugs

When executing the clean maven command, the following error occurs:

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.0:findbugs (findbugs) on
>    Unable to parse configuration of mojo
>   org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.0:findbugs for parameter
>   pluginArtifacts: Cannot assign configuration entry 'pluginArtifacts'
>   with value '${plugin.artifacts}' of type
>   java.util.Collections.UnmodifiableRandomAccessList to property of type
>   java.util.ArrayList.

I have version 2.6 for Apache Maven. Do you have any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: How are you executing the clean maven command?

Comment: I executed the clean command in the Intellij IDEA terminal: mvn clean

Comment: May I suggest that the accepted answer be changed to the one with the most upvotes? In this case, it's much better to update a plugin's version because of a bug fix in the plugin rather than downgrading the Maven version to an older one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it in this way:

- I deleted the .m2 and Apache Maven files
- I installed Apache Maven 2.5
- I created the .m2 folder and I added the setings.xml file to this folder

Comment: Why do you use such an old Maven version?

Comment: Because this version is used by my colleagues on the project.

Answer (score 40):

I had the same issue with Maven 3.6.0 as well. The problem seems to be a bug in the plugin, because it disappears starting from the plugin version 3.0.4. So the solution for me was to specify the version in the pom.xml:

```
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.4</version>
          <configuration>
            <failOnError>${maven.findbugs.failure.strict}</failOnError>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

Comment: This one did the trick for me, simply updating the artifactId version to 3.0.4 worked perfectly.

Comment: That helped, Thanks!. **Reason** : 3.0.0 depends on JDK 1.7. I found this reason in hbase source tree.

Comment: I had the same problem with findbugs `3.0.1`, and upgrading the plugin version to `3.0.4` fixed it! Just FYI though, FindBugs is deprecated (per https://gleclaire.github.io/findbugs-maven-plugin/) and you should ideally switch to spotbugs instead: https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migration.html#guide-for-migration-from-findbugs-3-0-to-spotbugs-3-1

Comment: Specifying maven 3.1.1 for the project containing this particular error instead of maven 3.6.x fixed the issue on my system.

Comment: had the same problem, could get out of it with this soluion.. thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Using mvn version 3.3.x might solve this problem. I got this error with 3.6.x.

Comment: Downgrading to maven 3.5.4 solved my issue. Thanks